# how to create/pass a completion handler callback as function parameter in c++11?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, callback, asynccallback

There is already tonnes of samples/codes out there that shows how to pass a function as callback into function parameter in C++11. Then the callback gets called into a separate function rather than into it's original caller function.

Let's say, i have the following sample code in **Objective-C**

```
- (void)calculateSizeWithCompletionBlock:(IPVWebImageCalculateSizeBlock)completionBlock {

    dispatch_async(self.ioQueue, ^{
        NSUInteger fileCount = 0;
        NSUInteger totalSize = 0;

        // Doing some time consuming task, that plays with some local(on this function scope) vars

        if (completionBlock) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                completionBlock(fileCount, totalSize);
            });
        }
    });
}

- (void)doSomething {
    NSUInteger var1 = 0;
    NSUInteger var2 = 0;

    [self calculateSizeWithCompletionBlock:^(NSUInteger fileCount, NSUInteger totalSize) {
        // Here, do things with fileCount, totalSize, var1, var2
        NSLog(@"fileCount: %lu, totalSize: %lu, var1: %lu, var2: %lu",(unsigned long)fileCount, (unsigned long)totalSize, (unsigned long)var1, (unsigned long)var2);
    }];
}
```

The straight question is how can i rewrite the above code in **C++11** ?
Where my callbacks will be called into the caller function so that it cal use caller functions local vars. I am aware of C++11's **Lambda, std::function, std::bind**, but not sure how to achieve that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This article I wrote might interest you: https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html

Comment: Are you trying to replace an obj-c closure with a c++ lambda in calls to GCD, or more generally? GCD has a c-style callback interface as well as a closure-based one. You can pass the address of the closure object and a function pointer to its static function. This can be wrapped in a callback function object.

Comment: I don't know Objective-C, but it seems to me that what you want is achieved with a `[&]` lambda capture.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1452834-dispatch_async_f?language=objc

Answer (score 2):

```
thread_pool& get_threadpool();
void run_on_ui_thread( std::function<void()> );

std::future<void> calculateSizeWithCompletionBlock(
  std::function<void(int fileCount, int totalSize)> completion
) {
  get_threadpool.queue(
    [completion]{
      int fileCount = 0;
      int totalSize = 0;

      // Doing some time consuming task, that plays with some local(on this function scope) vars

      if (completion) {
        RunOnUIThread( [fileCount, totalSize, completion]{
          completion(fileCount, totalSize);
        });
      }
    }
  );
}

void doSomething() {
  int var1 = 0;
  int var2 = 0;

  calculateSizeWithCompletionBlock(
    [var1, var2](int fileCount, int totalSize) {
      // Here, do things with fileCount, totalSize, var1, var2
      std::cout <<
        "fileCount: " << fileCount <<
        ", totalSize: " << totalSize <<
        ", var1: " << var1 <<
        ", var2: " << var2 << "\n";
    }
  );
}
```

this is the rough equivalent of your code.

I do not include `run_on_ui_thread` and `get_threadpool`, because both will depend on what context your C++ program is running in.

This is the only method of `thread_pool` I use:

```
struct thread_pool {
  std::future<void> queue( std::function<void()> );
};
```

basically, it is something that takes a function-like, and returns an object that lets you wait on that task's completion.

Unlike Objective-C, C++ runs on a large myriad of different environments.  The services that the OS or whatever other environment it is running in are not fixed.

There isn't, for example, an assumption that all C++ code runs in an interactive UI message-pumping environment.  The `run_on_ui_thread` implicitly assumes that, and would have to be written with the particular ui-thread-pump library in mind.

Some of the above code could be made marginally more efficient in C++14 with move-into-lambda.  In particular,

```
RunOnUIThread( [fileCount, totalSize, completion=std::move(completion)]{
  completion(fileCount, totalSize);
});
```

as in `calculateSizeWithCompletionBlock` we don't know how expensive `completion` is to copy.  In C++ you have more access to objects by-value, so sometimes you have to explicitly move things around.  On the plus side, this reduces the amount of allocations you'll have to do compared to objective-C.